# after converting date only getting date not time

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I am trying to convert date as mm/dd/yy format in Sql Server 2008 but after conversion i have only got formatted date but in my database there also time . my database value is :

```
2003-02-28 17:22:43.000
2003-02-28 17:22:43.000
2003-02-28 17:24:26.000
2003-02-28 17:24:26.000
2003-03-24 09:45:25.000
2003-03-24 09:45:25.000
2003-03-24 09:46:36.000
2003-03-24 09:46:36.000
2006-07-20 12:47:31.070
2003-03-27 15:44:53.000
2003-03-27 15:44:53.000
2003-03-27 15:51:56.000
2003-03-27 15:51:56.000
2003-03-27 16:05:03.000
```

my query for convert date format is

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), StatusDate, 101) AS Post_Converted,StatusDesc, RowVersionInitials from PurchaseOrderStatusHistory
```

and my output is

```
05/29/2014
05/29/2014
05/29/2014
05/29/2014
```

date is successfully formatted but the 'time' is missing . please suggest me how would i get the database time also .

Comment: as can be seen [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx) the 101 format for datetime outputs just the date. Choose another format that fits your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, SQL Server doesn't offer mm/dd/yyyy with the time component.  I would advise you to use format 120 -- the ISO standard format -- but you are asking specifically for this.

You can concatenate the values together:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), StatusDate, 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), StatusDate, 108) AS Post_Converted,
       StatusDesc, RowVersionInitials 
FROM PurchaseOrderStatusHistory;
```

Instead of 108, you might want 114:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), StatusDate, 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), StatusDate, 114) AS Post_Converted,
       StatusDesc, RowVersionInitials 
FROM PurchaseOrderStatusHistory;
```

This gives you the flexibility of adding milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

`CONVERT` accepts a third parameter, in your case `101` to specify the format.

[Find details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql)

What you'd need is - assumably - this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), StatusDate, 120)
```

... or another appropriate output format.

With SQL Server 2012+ there is `FORMAT()`, but with v2008 you cannot use this...